# jQuery/css3 triggering effects

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a slider and when the previous or next buttons are clicked I am trying to trigger the css3 effects to happen on each slide (Just like when the page loads)

Ive created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5c9T/6/

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    mode: 'fade'
});

$('.slider').addClass('load');

$('.bx-prev, .bx-next').click(function () {
    $('.slider').removeClass('load');
    $('.slider').addClass('load');
});
```

On the above I am trying to remove the load class and add it again so the css3 effects will be applied again but this doesnt seems to work.

*Edit, I missed remove/add 'load'

Comment: Okay well expound on what you would like to happen now?  Because the fiddle seems to do what you want.  After your `edits`

Comment: Better use the plugin for this. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the html actually needed to be refreshed for the css animation to take effect consistently. http://jsfiddle.net/g5c9T/13/

```
$('.bx-prev, .bx-next, .bx-pager-item').click(function(){
    $('.slider div').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome that works even better, thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/g5c9T/8/

```
$('.bx-prev, .bx-next').click(function () {
    $('.slider').removeClass('load');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').addClass('load');
    },10);
});
```

If you need better animation in jquery, check out this plugin and it helps much more ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit